# How can I update one (or a couple) files in a Google App Engine Flask App?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

If I'm just updating, say, my `main.py` file, is there a better way to update the app then running `gcloud app deploy`, which takes several minutes? I wouldn't think I need to completely blow up and rebuild the environment if I'm just updating one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must redeploy the service. App Engine isn't like a standard hosting site where you FTP single files, rather you upload a service that becomes containerized that can scale out to run on many instances. For a small site, this might feel weird, but consider a site serving huge amounts of traffic that might have hundreds of instances of code running that is automatically load balanced. How would you replace that single file in that situation across all your instances? So you upload a new version of a service and then you can migrate traffic to the new version either immediately or ramped up.

What you might consider an annoyance is part of the tradeoff that makes App Engine hugely powerful in not having to worry about how your app scales or is networked.

Comment: Thanks for describing the benefits of GAE, but I wouldn't agree it's a small annoyance. Many things I've attempted to do simply don't work locally, so having to wait several minutes for the app to launch increases the dev cycle  by an order of magnitude (e.g. what should take a couple hours to develop easily takes a day). It appears Google used to support an app_devserver but it doesn't work with Python 3 or the flexible environments.

Comment: The flexible environment does take longer to deploy. The team is committed to providing Python 3 on standard, they just don't have a timeline yet.